# Where can I find a mergZXing example stack?

Tags: livecode

Are there any example stack around for  mergZXing control? It seems simple but I am a bit unsure how it actually works.

I am eager to try things with QR codes.
Max Schafer

Answer (score 1):

The mergZXing zip archive contains a folder named "demo". This folder contains a fully working sample stack.
If you have not already a license of mergZXing and want information before a purchase you find detailed information about all functions/commands of mergZXing. On the main page at http://mergext.com select the menu entry "Externals" and select mergZXing or go directly to the mergXZing information [here](http://mergext.com/home/mergzxing/).

For example:

```
    put mergZXingGetBarcode() into tBarcode
```

presents a modal barcode reader and returns when a barcode is read or the user cancels. The returned value is put into tBarcode.